# Trouble getting AWS ecs-cli to pull from private docker repo

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cli, dockerhub

I'm trying to use the new [AWS ecs-cli](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-cli) and can't get it to pull from a private docker repo. I've got my docker credentials in an S3 bucket but how would I go about setting that in the cli? The documentation isn't very clear on this. I don't want to start ssh-ing into the actual instances either as that doesn't feel very clean. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that particular feature's still not available:

https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-cli/issues/24

Answer (score 0):

You just have to set the ECS_ENGINE_AUTH_TYPE and ECS_ENGINE_AUTH_DATA environment variables before the ECS agent is started.

My cluster hosts are configured using a cloudformation and this is the ECSServerLaunchConfig block that configures the instance to pull from private repositories by setting the variables in the ecs.config file.  I am using the AWS ECS Optimised AMI.

```
  "ECSServerLaunchConfig": {
  "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
  "Properties": {
    "IamInstanceProfile" : { "Fn::GetAtt" : ["InstanceProfile", "Arn"] },
    "ImageId" : { "Ref" : "AgentAMI" },
    "InstanceType": "c4.large",
    "SpotPrice": { "Ref": "SpotPrice" },
    "KeyName"  : { "Fn::GetAtt" : ["KeyPair", "Name"] },
    "SecurityGroups": [ { "Ref": "ECSServerSecurityGroup" } ],
    "BlockDeviceMappings" : [
      {
        "DeviceName" : { "Ref" : "EbsDeviceName" },
        "Ebs" : {
          "VolumeSize" : { "Ref" : "EbsDeviceSize" }
        }
      }
    ],
    "UserData" : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
      "#!/bin/bash\n",
      "mkfs -t ext4 /dev/xvdk\n",
      "mkdir /data\n",
      "mount /dev/xvdk /data\n",
      "chmod -R 777 /data\n",
      "yum install -y perl-DateTime perl-Sys-Syslog perl-LWP-Protocol-https perl-Digest-SHA\n",
      "yum install -y wget\n",
      "yum install -y unzip\n",
      "cd /home/ec2-user\n",
      "wget http://aws-cloudwatch.s3.amazonaws.com/downloads/CloudWatchMonitoringScripts-1.2.1.zip\n",
      "unzip CloudWatchMonitoringScripts-1.2.1.zip\n",
      "echo \"*/1 * * * * /home/ec2-user/aws-scripts-mon/mon-put-instance-data.pl --mem-util --disk-space-util --disk-path=/ --disk-path=/data --auto-scaling --from-cron\" >> mycron\n",
      "crontab mycron\n",
      "echo ECS_CLUSTER=", { "Ref" : "ECSCluster" }, " >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config\n",
      "echo ECS_ENGINE_AUTH_TYPE=dockercfg >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config\n",
      "echo ECS_ENGINE_AUTH_DATA='{\"https://index.docker.io/v1/\":{\"auth\":\"", { "Ref" : "PrivateRegistryAuthCode" },
          "\",\"email\":\"", { "Ref" : "PrivateRegistryEmail" }, "\"}}' >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config\n",
      "echo 'OPTIONS=\"--default-ulimit nofile=1024:4096 --mtu=1500\"' >> /etc/sysconfig/docker\n",
      "service docker restart\n",
      "start ecs"
    ]]}}
  }
},
```